# What can I do for Newly Potted Jap. Maples Have Leaves Drying up After One Day in the Sun?

Tags: japanese-maple

[image]I just planted six volunteer Japaneses maples. I did throw a couple rocks in the bottom, but not many. The spoil was a potting mixture that has been sitting in a healthy spot (worms and looks very rich). I left them in a early shade - later sun location and all of the leaves have started shriveling up. I put them in a greenhouse box with the doors nearly closed. Should I bring them inside until they are strong enough?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a few photos? And as for all new users, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [ask], to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: A little extra clarification please: when you say 'volunteer'  japanese maples, where did they come  from? Were they outdoors originally? And the potting mix, is it just garden soil, or from a bag of potting soil? And lastly, what part of the world are you in?